# EJB Transaction - static context - bad idea?

Tags: java, static, ejb, code-injection

### The Situation

Imagine the following:

There is an enum like this:

```
enum State{
  INITIAL{
    @Override
    public void proceed(){...}
  },
  NEXT_STATE{
    @Override
    public void proceed(){ ... }
  },
  //and so on
  TERMINATED;

  public void proceed(){}
}
```

Then there's an @Entity. This entity represents a usesase in an application which processes orders. Let's call it `ActivationUseCase`. `ActivationUseCase` (like any other class inheriting from my `UseCase` base class) has an attribute called state which contains a `State`.

And the last piece of the putzzle is an EJB 3.1 bean which retrieves an `ActivationUseCase` and calls proceed() on it.

The idea is to let the `@Entity` hold all information about it's possible states (the enum) and each state knows what to do when it has to `.proceed()`.

### The Problem

inside the proceed() method we have a static context. But we might want to call other EJBs. So someone started do do JNDI lookups (local) and call the beans we need.
IMHO that's quite ugly and dangerous, but that's not the question here.

Just to be clear, here's a stack of pseudo-calls:

```
    MyServiceBean.myServiceMethod()
    |- ActivationUseCase.proceed()
       |- ManuallyLookedUpEJB.anotherServiceMethod()
```

So `MyServiceBean.myServiceMethod()` starts a Transaction, retrieves the `ActivationUseCase` instance to call `proceed()` on it. Then we lookup `ManuallyLookedUpEJB` (new InitialContext()...) and call `anotherServiceMethod()`.

### The Question

What happens to the Transaction? Where does it start? Will it cover `anotherServiceMethod()`? How i can i debug this?

### Disclaimer

I don't want to discuss the enum-contains-logic construct (now). In fact i'm gathering reasons for refactoring (rewriting) the whole thing. I just need some reasons to support my claim that this construct is not a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

The transaction will propagate like with any other method call. So, unless `ManuallyLookedUpEJB.anotherServiceMethod()` has a REQUIRES_NEW transaction propagation, it will execute in the same transaction as the one started by `MyServiceBean.myServiceMethod()`.

Comment: thanks for the reply. The manual JNDI-lookup in the static context inside an @Entity is not a problem? Nice.

Comment: What do you mean by "in the static context"?

Comment: the code in State.[ENUM_VALUE].proceed() is executed in a static context. That's where we do our JNDI lookup to ManuallyLookedUpEJB and call anotherServiceMethod() on it. That's what i mean by static context